# Mockito - verify call on a matched parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, testing, mockito

I have the following scenario. Code I'm testing (kotlin/JVM/Spring Boot)

```
private val client: WebClient, // injected by Spring Boot.

// (...) 
    
client.post()
   .uri(uri)
   .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("query", query))
   .header(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.toString())

// (...)
```

`client` is a `WebClient`.

In my testing code I want to check that the `client` is called with uri and query matching an arbitrary predicate. I came up with this:

```
@MockBean private val hgWebClient: WebClient,  // injected by Spring Boot Test.

// (...)

fun mockPostResponse(
    bodyMatch: (String) -> Boolean,  // in Java it would be Predicate<String>
    uriMatch: (URI) -> Boolean,
    response: String
): WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec {
    val uriReceiver: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec = mock()
 // in Java it would be "when"
    whenever(hgWebClient.post()).thenReturn(uriReceiver)
    val bodyReceiver: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec = mock()

 // here matching with argThat works just fine
    whenever(uriReceiver.uri(argThat<URI>(uriMatch))).thenReturn(bodyReceiver)

    val spec3: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec = mock()

// here I have to use "any" because
// .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("query", argThat(bodyMatch))) won't work
        whenever(bodyReceiver.body(any<BodyInserters.FormInserter<String>>())).thenReturn(spec3) 

    val spec4: WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec = mock()
    whenever(spec3.header(any(), any())).thenReturn(spec4)
    whenever(
            spec4.exchangeToMono(any<Function<ClientResponse, Mono<String>>>())
    ).thenAnswer {
        Mono.fromSupplier { mockHttpResponse(response) }
    }
    // return both bodyReceiver and uriReceiver
}
```

Later I want to verify that these methods were called, so

```
mockPostResponse(...)

// works just fine
verify(receivers.uriReceiver) { 1 * { this.uri(argThat(uriMatch)) }  }

// No idea what to put there so it verifies that "query" in BodyInserters.fromFormData("query", query)
// matches the "bodyMatch" predicate
verify(receivers.bodyReceiver) { 1 * { this.body(???) }  }
```

To sum up, the specific problem is that I don't know how to mock a method call which argument itself is a mock, *on which* I verify that a call to a static function was made (or I'm missing something obvious). I think it's something with `BodyInserters.fromFormData` being a static function (?).

How to properly mock this scenario and actually verify that arguments match predicates?

Comment: Static calls aren't "made" on individual objects anyway, so no way you can verify that. Maybe you could turn to powermockito for that, but then, powermockito is almost always the wrong answer.

Comment: Consider using Mockk (https://mockk.io/) in a kotlin project. It supports mocking of static functions and is generally designed for easier use with kotlin's syntax.

Comment: @Can_of_awe I used mockk but dropped it during migration from Micronaut to Spring Boot because it doesn't work seamlessly with \@MockBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround, which isn't that bad

Create a wrapper around the static Spring Boot factory and inject that in real code.

```
/**
 * Wrapper around BodyInserters static factory
 */
@Service
class BodyInsertersFactory {
    fun fromFormData(name: String, value: String): BodyInserters.FormInserter<String> =
        BodyInserters.fromFormData(name, value)
}
```

Then in tests:

```
    @SpyBean private val bodyInsertersFactory: BodyInsertersFactory,

// (...)

verify(bodyInsertersFactory) { 1 * { fromFormData(any(), argThat(bodyMatch)) } }
```